# Can Apache/MySQL/PHP be installed on Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, wamp

Have only used Professional addition, but apparent new laptops come with Home editions.

Can WAMP install on Win10 Home or do I need to request an "upgrade" on the installed OS.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there should be nothing preventing installation of WAMP on Home versions of Windows 10. Please [edit] your question to include specific details of the actual problem(s) you are encountering.

Comment: Have you tried? What makes you think it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason WAMP should not work on a Home license of Windows 10.

The differences between Home and Enterprise do not encompass third party system or capabilities.

Answer (score -1):

As stated on https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

> Apache httpd for Microsoft Windows is available from a number of third party vendors.

Among which is XAMPP which I recommend. You can install it following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvwUsYdO33A

Comment: Have WAMP running on Win 10 Pro edition, the question was can it run on Win 10 Home edition. Unable to access the apache site from work for no apparent reason.